# where to add space between asterisks

Tags: java

Where/how to add space in between asterisks,
this is what i've done so far..

```
int i, j, k;
int n = 5;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}

for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: @KevinEsche is OP first question. So, you can help new user by formatting question by yourself or by linking some guide, but this kind of comments are rude, not constructive and not allowed in stack overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual output is this:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

> Where/how to add space in between asterisks?

If your expected output is this:

```
        * 
      * * * 
    * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * 
      * * * 
        *
```

Use an extra space in each print statement

```
int i, j, k;
int n = 5;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}

for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Check here a [working demo](https://ideone.com/SPxlYY)

Comment: I added an online demo, let me know if this is what you expect, if no, please add expected output editing your question, thanks! :)

Comment: @Franz it's up to you [mark an answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Thanks

Comment: @JordiCastilla dang Jordi, you are quick on the draw to answer these Java tags!

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand your question correctly, you should be able to replace "**" with "* *" if you want to " add space in between asterisks". Something like this:

```
String asterisks = "**";
asterisks = asterisks.replaceAll("\\*\\*, \\* \\*);
```